# Intersection of canal surface with line

Tags: geometry, numerical-methods

A canal surface is the surface formed by sweeping a variable-radius sphere along a path.  I'd like to find the intersection points of a line with this surface.

Let $t \in [0,1]$ parameterise the path and $\mathbf{c}(t)$ and $r(t)$ represent the centre and radius of the sphere along the path, then we can define the canal surface as the zeros of the signed field $D$:

$$
D(\mathbf{v}) = \inf_{t\in [0,1]} \left( ||\mathbf{v} - \mathbf{c}(t)||^2 - r(t)^2 \right)
$$

In my case I can assume that $\mathbf{c}(t)$ and $r(t)$ are at most quadratic polynomials of $t$.  As such I can easily evaluate this field for a given $\mathbf{v}$ by finding the zeros of the derivative of the terms in the infemum wrt $t$ (which is just solving a cubic), then just taking the minimum for these $t$ values.

If $\mathbf{v}$ is constrained to a line, I can define some constants $\mathbf{p}$ and $\mathbf{d}$ such that the intersection points are the solution to:

$$
D(\mathbf{p} + s\mathbf{d}) = 0
$$

I'm a bit stumped how to solve this.

My question is: what numerical methods exist to allow me to solve for $s$?  Or is there a simpler way to state the problem?

Answer (score 1):

After more reading around I can answer my own question: read the 1986(!) Phd Thesis "On new types of solid models and their visualization with ray tracing." by Jack van Wijk.

Author homepage: http://www.win.tue.nl/~vanwijk/
Thesis (pdf): http://repository.tudelft.nl/assets/uuid:19fa16c3-33fc-4f10-9a40-1eeb206531a8/TR%20DISS%201506(1).PDF

There is a substitution to solve the equation directly. When the centre and radius are polynomials of degree $d$, this requires solving a polynomial of degree $2(2d - 1)$.

Comment: It's not Jack but _Jarke_ J. van Wijk. I have the book here in my book shelves.